# Pass variable to included template in django

Tags: python, django, templates, variables, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass variable to child template:

```
{% block footer %}
    {% include '_footer.html'  with var="foo" %}
{% endblock footer %}
```

but I am getting django error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'with'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this error is not possible with the code shown. Show us the exact code you're using, by copy&pasting and the entire template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must declare variable first then include child template

```
{% block footer %}
    {% with var="foo" %}
        {% include  "_footer.html" %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: another solution being to use an `inclusion_tag` so you can explicitely pass arguments...